# VHDL synax error in state machine

Tags: syntax, vhdl

I am having difficulty finding a syntax error in my coding. Any help will be greatly appreciated. My synthesizer says the error is located at the state when blowoncompon>=   however I think the error is somewhere else because when I commit that state of code out the error moves to the next state.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity question4 is
 Port (
 --System Clock Declaration--------------------------
 clk: in std_logic;

 --Button Inputs-------------------------------------
 btnL: in std_logic; --
 btnU: in std_logic; --Clear
 btnD: in std_logic; --Reset

 sw: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 led: out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
 );
 end question4;

 architecture Behavioral of question4 is 

 constant active: std_logic := '1'; 
 constant bloweron: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := "000000011111111";
 constant compon: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := "1111111000000000";
 signal clear: std_logic := btnU; 
 signal reset: std_logic := btnD; 


 type states is (blowoncompoff, 
                blowoffcompoff, 
                blowoncompon);

 signal CurrentState: states; 
 signal NextState: states; 

begin 

motorstatetrans: process(currentsate)
begin

    if clear = active then 
        currentstate <= blowoffcompoff; 
    end if; 

    case currentstate is

       when blowoncompon>=   --------Why syntax error near here
            led <= bloweron;  
            led <= compon;

            if currenttemp=settemp then
                Nextstate <= blowoncompoff;

            elsif
                currenttemp>settemp then 
                    Nextstate <= bloweroncompon; 
            end if; 

       when blowoncompoff >= 
            led <= bloweron; 

            if currenttemp < settemp then 
                Nextstate <= bloweroncompon; 

            elsif current temp = set temp then 
                Nextstate <= blowoffcompoff; 

      when blowoffcompoff >=

            if current temp < settemp then 
                Nextstate <= blowoncompon; 

    end case; 
end process;
```

Comment: No, the error is right where the tool is indicating. ` when blowoncompon>=   --------Why syntax error near here`. IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.9 Case statement, the syntax is *case_statement_alternative ::= when choices =>
sequence_of_statements*. Instead of ">=" you should be using "=>" prior to a sequence of statements (one or more sequential statement, 10.1). Show your error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
when blowoncompon>=   --------Why syntax error near here
```

This is not VHDL syntax, like the error says. Just google it: [VHDL Case Statement](http://www.vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00014.htm)

```
when blowoncompon =>
```

But your code is missing a lot of `end if;`s so it will still not work.

Answer (score -1):

According its entity declaration (`clk`), your state machine is probably a synchronous circuit. But your design is not a synchronous one: it does not use its clock.

Comment: I have not added the clock yet. I noticed the error occurred as soon as I created the first state. I am creating a clock divider signal that will be sent to the different states themselves in the form of an if statement to slow things down so they will be visible with the human eye. I didnt think lack of a clock signal would create an error but I will go ahead and create it and insert the signal into the states and see what happens.

Comment: not my down-vote, but you are indeed not correct imho: A state machine does not have to be a synchronous circuit at all. Actually, often in asynchronous designs state machine are the best way to guide circuit behavior.

Comment: In a VHDL model of a state machine where an input port is named `clk` and commented as *System Clock Declaration*, we can probably assume that the target class of designs is not asynchronous, but you are technically correct, [J.H.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6717178/j-h-bonarius), a state machine can also be asynchronous. Edited my answer accordingly.

And I do not mind down-votes, even when I do not understand them.